# drm:drm_edid_block_valid slowing down booting

Tags: boot, display

`drm_edid_block_valid` is appearing a lot in `dmesg`, where I am looking for the reasons of my slow booting process. Here is the output:

```
[   13.884900] audit: type=1400 audit(1467376765.370:11): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=627 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   17.774473] [drm:drm_edid_block_valid [drm]] *ERROR* EDID checksum is invalid, remainder is 209
[   17.774484] Raw EDID:
[   17.774486]      00 ff ff ff ff ff ff 00 22 f0 54 29 01 01 01 01
[   17.774486]      1b 17 01 04 a5 34 20 78 23 4c a5 a7 55 4d a2 26
[   17.774487]      10 50 54 21 08 00 d1 c0 81 c0 81 40 81 80 95 00
[   17.774488]      a9 40 b3 00 01 00 d1 c0 81 c0 81 40 81 80 95 00
[   17.774488]      36 00 06 44 21 00 00 1a 00 00 00 fd 00 18 3c 18
[   17.774489]      50 11 00 0a 20 20 20 20 20 20 00 00 00 fc 00 48
[   17.774490]      50 20 5a 52 32 34 34 30 77 0a 20 20 00 00 00 ff
[   17.774490]      00 43 4e 34 33 32 37 30 4a 4c 5a 0a 20 20 01 a6
[   22.023647] cgroup: new mount options do not match the existing superblock, will be ignored
```

And also this:

```
[   35.700972] WARNING: CPU: 2 PID: 498 at /build/linux-BvkamA/linux-4.4.0/drivers/gpu/drm/i915/intel_display.c:1144 intel_disable_pipe+0x2b6/0x2c0 [i915]()
[   35.700973] pipe_off wait timed out
[   35.700974] Modules linked in: intel_rapl x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic snd_hda_intel coretemp input_leds joydev snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core kvm snd_hwdep snd_pcm irqbypass snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi crct10dif_pclmul snd_seq crc32_pclmul snd_seq_device snd_timer hp_wmi ie31200_edac sparse_keymap aesni_intel edac_core snd aes_x86_64 soundcore lpc_ich serio_raw lrw gf128mul glue_helper ablk_helper 8250_fintek mac_hid tpm_infineon cryptd parport_pc ppdev lp parport autofs4 hid_generic usbhid hid i915 i2c_algo_bit drm_kms_helper syscopyarea sysfillrect e1000e sysimgblt psmouse fb_sys_fops ahci drm libahci ptp pps_core wmi fjes video
[   35.700999] CPU: 2 PID: 498 Comm: plymouthd Not tainted 4.4.0-28-generic #47-Ubuntu
[   35.701000] Hardware name: Hewlett-Packard HP Compaq Elite 8300 SFF/3397, BIOS K01 v02.90 07/16/2013
[   35.701001]  0000000000000286 000000000d3335aa ffff88040aa0bac8 ffffffff813eb1a3
[   35.701003]  ffff88040aa0bb10 ffffffffc027ca70 ffff88040aa0bb00 ffffffff81081102
[   35.701004]  ffff880035a10000 0000000000071008 00000000fffefde4 0000000000071008
[   35.701005] Call Trace:
[   35.701010]  [<ffffffff813eb1a3>] dump_stack+0x63/0x90
[   35.701013]  [<ffffffff81081102>] warn_slowpath_common+0x82/0xc0
[   35.701014]  [<ffffffff8108119c>] warn_slowpath_fmt+0x5c/0x80
[   35.701026]  [<ffffffffc020f376>] intel_disable_pipe+0x2b6/0x2c0 [i915]
[   35.701038]  [<ffffffffc020f72c>] ironlake_crtc_disable+0x8c/0x7c0 [i915]
[   35.701049]  [<ffffffffc020b0ec>] ? intel_crtc_disable_planes+0xdc/0xf0 [i915]
[   35.701060]  [<ffffffffc0218990>] intel_atomic_commit+0x110/0x6f0 [i915]
[   35.701071]  [<ffffffffc00687de>] ? drm_atomic_check_only+0x18e/0x590 [drm]
[   35.701079]  [<ffffffffc0067d1f>] ? drm_atomic_set_crtc_for_connector+0x6f/0xe0 [drm]
[   35.701087]  [<ffffffffc0068c17>] drm_atomic_commit+0x37/0x60 [drm]
[   35.701092]  [<ffffffffc016fb16>] drm_atomic_helper_set_config+0x76/0xb0 [drm_kms_helper]
[   35.701099]  [<ffffffffc0057e42>] drm_mode_set_config_internal+0x62/0x100 [drm]
[   35.701106]  [<ffffffffc005c362>] drm_mode_setcrtc+0x3d2/0x4f0 [drm]
[   35.701112]  [<ffffffffc004d742>] drm_ioctl+0x152/0x540 [drm]
[   35.701119]  [<ffffffffc005bf90>] ? drm_mode_setplane+0x1b0/0x1b0 [drm]
[   35.701121]  [<ffffffff81220b6f>] do_vfs_ioctl+0x29f/0x490
[   35.701123]  [<ffffffff8106b554>] ? __do_page_fault+0x1b4/0x400
[   35.701124]  [<ffffffff81220dd9>] SyS_ioctl+0x79/0x90
[   35.701126]  [<ffffffff818276b2>] entry_SYSCALL_64_fastpath+0x16/0x71
[   35.701127] ---[ end trace c5b67dc3bdb687af ]---
[   35.765519] [drm:ironlake_crtc_disable [i915]] *ERROR* failed to disable transcoder B
[   35.768073] [drm:intel_set_pch_fifo_underrun_reporting [i915]] *ERROR* uncleared pch fifo underrun on pch transcoder A
[   35.768091] [drm:intel_pch_fifo_underrun_irq_handler [i915]] *ERROR* PCH transcoder A FIFO underrun
[   35.768114] [drm:intel_set_pch_fifo_underrun_reporting [i915]] *ERROR* uncleared pch fifo underrun on pch transcoder B
[   35.768130] [drm:intel_pch_fifo_underrun_irq_handler [i915]] *ERROR* PCH transcoder B FIFO underrun
[   35.855896] [drm:drm_edid_block_valid [drm]] *ERROR* EDID checksum is invalid, remainder is 212
[   35.855897] Raw EDID:
[   35.855898]      00 ff ff ff ff ff ff 00 22 f0 54 29 01 01 01 01
[   35.855898]      1b 17 01 04 a5 34 20 78 23 4c a5 a7 55 4d a2 26
[   35.855899]      10 50 54 21 08 00 d1 c0 81 c0 81 40 55 4d a2 26
[   35.855899]      a9 40 b3 00 01 01 28 3c 80 a0 70 b0 23 40 30 20
[   35.855899]      36 00 06 44 21 00 00 1a 00 00 00 fd 00 18 3c 18
[   35.855899]      50 11 00 0a 20 20 20 20 20 20 00 00 00 fc 00 48
[   35.855900]      50 20 5a 52 32 34 34 30 77 0a 20 20 00 00 00 ff
[   35.855900]      00 43 4e 34 33 32 37 30 4a 4c 5a 0a 20 20 01 a6
[   58.088907] Raw EDID:
[   58.088911]      00 ff ff ff 01 00 01 00 02 02 06 00 00 00 00 7b
[   58.088912]      1b 17 01 04 a5 34 20 78 23 4c a5 a7 55 4d a2 26
[   58.088912]      10 50 54 21 08 00 d1 c0 81 c0 81 40 81 80 95 00
[   58.088913]      a9 40 b3 00 01 01 28 3c 80 a0 70 b0 23 40 30 20
[   58.088914]      36 00 06 44 21 00 00 1a 00 00 00 fd 00 18 3c 18
[   58.088914]      50 11 00 0a 20 20 20 20 20 20 00 00 00 fc 00 48
[   58.088915]      50 20 5a 52 32 34 34 30 77 0a 20 20 00 00 00 ff
[   58.088916]      00 43 4e 34 33 32 37 30 4a 4c 5a 0a 20 20 01 a6
[   58.091785] [drm:drm_edid_block_valid [drm]] *ERROR* EDID checksum is invalid, remainder is 203
[   58.091786] Raw EDID:
[   58.091786]      00 ff ff ff ff ff ff 00 22 f0 54 29 01 01 01 01
[   58.091787]      1b 17 01 04 a5 34 20 78 23 4c 54 29 01 01 01 01
[   58.091788]      10 50 54 21 08 00 d1 c0 81 c0 81 40 81 80 95 00
[   58.091788]      a9 40 b3 00 01 01 28 3c 80 a0 70 b0 23 40 30 20
[   58.091789]      36 00 06 44 21 00 00 1a 00 00 00 fd 00 18 3c 18
[   58.091790]      50 11 00 0a 20 20 20 20 20 20 00 00 00 fc 00 48
[   58.091790]      50 20 5a 52 32 34 34 30 77 0a 20 20 00 00 00 ff
[   58.091800]      00 43 4e 34 33 32 37 30 4a 4c 5a 0a 20 20 01 a6
[   58.094679] [drm:drm_edid_block_valid [drm]] *ERROR* EDID checksum is invalid, remainder is 71
[   58.094680] Raw EDID:
[   58.094681]      00 ff ff ff ff ff ff 00 22 f0 54 29 01 01 01 01
[   58.094681]      1b 17 01 04 a5 34 20 78 23 4c a5 a7 55 4d a2 26
[   58.094682]      10 50 54 21 08 00 d1 c0 81 c0 81 40 81 80 95 00
[   58.094683]      a9 40 b3 00 01 01 28 3c 80 a0 70 b0 23 40 30 20
[   58.094683]      36 00 06 44 21 00 00 1a 00 00 00 fd 23 40 30 20
[   58.094684]      50 11 00 0a 20 20 20 20 20 20 00 00 00 fc 00 48
[   58.094685]      50 20 5a 52 32 34 34 30 77 0a 20 20 00 00 00 ff
[   58.094685]      00 43 4e 34 33 32 37 30 4a 4c 5a 0a 20 20 01 a6
[   58.097544] [drm:drm_edid_block_valid [drm]] *ERROR* EDID checksum is invalid, remainder is 160
[   58.097545] Raw EDID:
[   58.097545]      00 ff ff ff ff ff ff 00 22 f0 54 29 01 01 01 01
[   58.097546]      1b 17 01 04 a5 34 20 78 23 4c a5 a7 55 4d a2 26
[   58.097547]      10 50 54 21 08 00 d1 c0 81 c0 81 40 81 80 95 00
[   58.097547]      a9 40 b3 00 01 01 28 3c 80 a0 70 b0 23 40 30 20
[   58.097548]      36 00 06 44 21 00 00 1a 00 00 00 fd 00 18 3c 18
[   58.097549]      50 11 00 0a 21 00 00 1a 00 00 00 fd 00 18 3c 18
[   58.097549]      50 20 5a 52 32 34 34 30 77 0a 20 20 00 00 00 ff
[   58.097550]      00 43 4e 34 33 32 37 30 4a 4c 5a 0a 20 20 01 a6
[   58.097552] i915 0000:00:02.0: DP-1: EDID block 0 invalid.
```

#### Some Additional Information

As this appears to be about the display, here's some additional information.

My setup features two monitors, a HP ZR2440w, and an older Dell monitor (which I've set up vertically). I also notice that during the booting process, when the login screen appears, it appears first only on my secondary monitor (the Dell one), and it ignores the vertical configuration (so I'd have to turn my head to actually read it). After a few seconds then, it moves the information to the main monitor, and fixes the orientation of the secondary monitor.

I searched around for `drm:drm_edid_block_valid`, but I couldnt find anything related to the booting process itself. What's going on?